# problemas al leer json con python

Tags: python, json

Estoy intentado abrir un archivo json, pero no lo consigo, el mimos código a los demás les funciona, pero a mi no.

Este es mi código:

```
import json
f = open('evolucion_del_salario_medio_anual_en_andalucia.json','r').read()
f = json.loads(f)
anios = []
for i in f['Respuesta']['Datos']['Metricas']:
    anios.append(i['Datos'])
anios
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
----> 3 f = json.loads(f)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

¿Cómo puedo abrirlo?
```

el json es el siguiente:

```
{
    "Url": "www.epdata.es/salario-medio-anual-comunidad/97b8cd56-8314-4891-b043-7b5760666fff/andalucia/290",
    "Respuesta": {
        "Id": "97b8cd56-8314-4891-b043-7b5760666fff",
        "Url": "www.epdata.es/salario-medio-anual-comunidad/97b8cd56-8314-4891-b043-7b5760666fff/andalucia/290",
        "Titulo": "Evolución del salario medio anual en Andalucía",
        "Subtitulo": "",
        "Datos": {
            "Metricas": [
                {
                    "Id": 0,
                    "Nombre": "Salarios a nivel anual - Euros para total como sexo del asalariado, total como tipo de contrato y Andalucía como comunidad autónoma",
                    "SonDatosNumericos": true,
                    "Fuente": "INE",
                    "Clasificacion": null,
                    "Unidad": "Euros",
                    "Escala": "Unidades",
                    "EscalaFactorPotencia10": 0,
                    "Datos": [
                        {
                            "Agno": 2008,
                            "Periodo": "Año",
                            "Parametro": "2008",
                            "Valor": 20138.560546875,
                            "Estado": "Definitivo",
                            "Notas": null
                        },
                        {
                            "Agno": 2009,
                            "Periodo": "Año",
                            "Parametro": "2009",
                            "Valor": 20906.330078125,
                            "Estado": "Definitivo",
                            "Notas": null
                        },
```

El resultado esperado es una lista en la que tenga el valor,también necesito otra del parametro, pero con resolver el valor iria bien.

```
anios = [20138.560546875,20906.330078125,20906.330078125...]
```

Comment: Reusar las variables es **pecado mortal**. No tiene costo dar a cada cosa un nombre apropiado y le facilita la vida a todo el mundo.

Comment: dime que quieres decir exactamente y modifico la pregunta, no se que falta

Comment: Primero, el título está mal, pues de hecho abriste el archivo y lo leistes en la línea 2. Segundo, agrega el json a la pregunta (si es muy largo, solo una parte representativa). Tercero, muestra (o explica) el resultado que buscas.

Comment: ¿Usas windows? Añade el parámetro `encoding="utf-8"` cuando abres el fichero con `open()`.

Comment: El json tiene que ser válido, algo que permite llegar hasta la línea que te da error.

Comment: encoding="utf-8" no me funciona :(

Comment: algo que no va bien hay si, pero a los demás este mismito código les funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene toda la pinta de que al inicio de tu archivo json (pero no en el "los demás") hay un carácter invisible llamado [BOM](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes). Muchos editores de windows tienen la "manía" de incluir ese byte al inicio del archivo cuando lo guardan como utf8.

Para que ese carácter sea ignorado pr python al momento de leer el archivo debes abrir éste con el parámetro adicional `encoding="utf-8-sig"`

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema bastante comun, pero lo que pasa es que estas ocupando el metodo incorrecto para cargar el JSON. Si le hechas un ojo a [la documentacion de la libreria json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), notaras que provee dos metodos para cargar: `load` y `loads`.

Para cargar JSON desde archivos debes ocupar `json.load(fp)`.

Tu estas ocupando `json.loads(s)` (nota la "s" al final del nombre del metodo). Este metodo sirve para parsear strings que contienen *JSON* a un objeto de Python. Por ejemplo:

```
> import json
> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Comment: Sií pero es que ella realmente está pasando un string a `json.loads()` pues, si te fijas, hay un `.read()` al final de la primera línea.

Comment: Toda la razon! Me deje llevar por el nombre de la variable, y no me habia fijado en ese read . Otra razon más para poner nombres descriptivos a las variables.

Comment: Susana, lo que puedes hacer es quitarle el `read()` al final de la llamada a `open` y pasarle el file pointer que retorna `open` directamente a la funcion `load(fp)` como describí arriba. Puede que el metodo `load(fp)` sea más robusto que manualmente llamar a `read()` y ocupar `loads(s)`.

Comment: Peor que eso: usa el mismo nombre para una cosa distinta en cada línea del programa.